# Unit testing of Dao and Websocket. Dependency injection

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection

I have quite developed my application, made in Flutter. The app is a real time which consumes a WebSocket API. The problem came when i tried to generate testing to this App.
The general schema of my app is this:

```
class Dao<Entity> {
  final _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(Constants.streamURL));
  // Then other methods listen this stream and convert data from JSON to model DTOs and put it in another Stream of DTOs`
```

Then a `viewModel` uses Dao to listen DTOs stream and fill a list and notify listeners:

```
class PersonViewmodel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _personDao = Dao<Person>();
  List<Person> _persons = [];
  void getPersons() {
    _personDao.getStream.listen((list)=>_persons=list);
  }
}
```

And then is called by view with `ChangeNotifierProvider`.

This code makes very difficult to mock that private dependencies. I read in some places that initialize dependencies by hardcoding them in the field or inside constructor is a bad practice. It should be injected through a constructor instead. the problem in that when i instantiate i will need to put all the nested dependencies, something like this:

```
final _personViewModel = PersonViewmodel(Dao<Person>(WebSocketChannel, Constants.streamURL));
```

I also will make integration testing with real API connection with a testing account and data, but it won't be isolated and certain conditions such as no internet, can't be automated.

What do you think, do i need to refactor my app to inject the dependencies through constructor rathen than hardcoding the field?
To what extent is it bad practice to hardcode or initialize fields in a class, in its declaration, or in the constructor body? Is it always?